# \ converts to \\ while reading from plist

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I am using `arrayWithContentsOfFile` method to create an array as shown below:

```
NSArray *temp = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:mBackupSetFilePath];
```

Above syntax works fine for normal cases, but if the `.plist` contains data like C\D, C\\D it gets converted to C\\D, C\\\\D.

[image]

passing this array to a function and in that function these values are appearing as  C\\D, C\\\\D. instead of C\D, C\\D .

Comment: Please show what's in that file.

Comment: indeed, on the log-console \ will appear as \\ because that is an escape char. but in the engine they are stored as are in the file.

Comment: @holex agree with you but I am looking for a way to read contents as it is, One solution is iterate array and for each object use - stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\\\" withString:@"\\", but I think its not feasible.

Comment: @akhilshrivastav, usually you read the content as is (printing it on the console is another question), if you invoke the method `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:` then you will modify the original content. is that your goal?

Comment: @holex goal is to read content as it is in the plist, so that i can write it to some text file .

Comment: @akhilshrivastav, if your goal it getting the file's content as is, just read it and use it, you should not make any changes on it...

Comment: @akhilshrivastav did you tried writing the string to the file? i believe that the framework will remove the extra ` \\ ` i.e. if you intent to write ` \\ ` framework will read it as ` \\\\ ` and when you write it to file it will remove extra ` \ ` and use ` \\ ` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Console logs are eliminating the escape characters. Just Wrote simple test to verify.

Content of AppDelegate:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    NSArray *plist = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"plist"]];
    [self takeArray:plist];
}

- (void)takeArray:(NSArray *)arr {
    NSLog(@"%@", arr);
}
```

Content of plist file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
        <string>/Users/Test/C\ D</string>
        <string>/Users/Test/C\ E</string>
        <string>/Users/Test/C\ F</string>
</array>
</plist>
```

In Console log `NSLog` will print:

```
(
    "/Users/Test/C\\ D",
    "/Users/Test/C\\ E",
    "/Users/Test/C\\ F"
)
```

But the actual values shown by debugger and used by function will be:

```
(
/Users/Test/C\ D,
/Users/Test/C\ E,
/Users/Test/C\ F
)
```